# How to delete a non-empty store in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have a workspace in with many stores, while i'm trying to delete the store an error shows up saying that it is unable to delete non-empty store. I tried to delete it after adding shape file the store, but only the shapefile is deleted.

Comment: how are you trying to delete the store, through the UI or REST? Is there an error message in the log file?